# How to pass a value to this react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have the following code structure:

```js
const AuthUserProvider = (props: UserProviderProps, user: User) => {
  const ctx = {}; // gets some other user info from different API
  return <UserContext.Provider value={ctx} {...props} />;
};

export const UserProvider = (props: UserProviderProps) => {
  const user = {}; // gets user info from via API call
  return <AuthUserProvider {...props} />;
}
```

I want to be able to pass that `user` object into the `AuthUserProvider` component, but when I try the following:

```js
return <AuthUserProvider {...props} user={value} />;
```

I get this error:

> TS2322: Property 'user' does not exist on type ......

How do I pass this user object into the `AuthUserProvider` component? And why doesn't the above work?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to add `user` to the `UserProviderProps` definition.

Comment: The current definition is `type UserProviderProps = ProviderProps<UserValue>;` - how do I add `user`?

Answer (score 0):

As already was mentioned by [@Yanick Bélanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9504406/yanick-b%c3%a9langer)

> You simply have to add user to the UserProviderProps definition.

```
// Your `UserProviderProps` interface 
{
  // Existing UserProviderProps
  user: User
}
```

so function prototype will become like

```
const AuthUserProvider = (props: UserProviderProps) => {};
```

Or, if you don't want to touch `UserProviderProps`'s content, change function prototype as follows

```
const AuthUserProvider = (props: {userProvider: UserProviderProps, user: User}) => {};
```